# I want to Download the wiki pages at 'Oblivion:Oblivion-UESP wiki' without getting the sidebar links to other wiki content

Tags: recursion, firefox, download, wget, sidebar

I tried to use wget to download the 'Oblivion:Oblivion-uesp wiki' `https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Oblivion' which is about the crpg game 'Oblivion'. the game is old and I worry that someday the wiki will go away. It encompasses a large volume of information that would be extremely hard to get doing each page individually and of course the pages would not be linked in the offline copy. wget started downloading other content as well due to the side bar links. Is it possible to access the main page and its links without the sidebar links? All of the linked pages also have sidebars.

I simply tried to use wget to download the wiki . It started downloading other content linked by the sidebar. I searched Firefox extensions but could not find anything appropriate.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> Oblivion:Oblivion-uesp wiki

I investigated that site and concluded that content pertaining to Oblivion game has `blivion` somewhere in url, e.g. `https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Alchemy` therefore it is possible to use [`--accept-regex ulregex`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options.html) option to get good enough determination of what to do download, I suggest following command

```
wget -r --accept-regex ".*blivion.*" "https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Oblivion"
```

Please test it yourself and write if it fetches what you want, without too much garbage. Keep in mind that it might get content not related to oblivion (game) if substring `blivion` is present url, e.g. you might have spell *damn the rest oblivion* from another game, but hopefully false positive should be acceptable low.